# Imagick PHP - Replacing solid color area with an image fill?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm new to Imagemagick and PHP imagick.
I've been searching for days for a function or method that will allow me to replace a solid color or transparent area in one image with the contents of another image.

For example:

Image #1 is a pre-made picture of a person with the face area removed and filled with solid white (#FFFFFF).

Image #2 is a transparent PNG of a face, where the face is has been cut-out and the background is transparent.

I want to merge these two images together and fill the solid white area of image #1 with the face on image #2.

Is this possible with imagick? I haven't found any information on google about this, but I've come close with masking functions and composite functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using ImageMagick. It is called "Composite", overlapping one image to another. For more details goto [script example](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php?ImageMagick=qqmnmp2cu8s1j991g9qdrb7bm5)

Comment: I have investigated the function Imagick::compositeImage but it only seems to merge the two images together based on pixel co-ordinates given. I need to replace an entire area that contains a given solid color, while discarding any clipped areas (for a perfect blend). So far I cant find the method of doing this.